# What is the inspiration for 11th Doctor clothing style?

Tags: doctor-who

Where did Doctor Who creators got their inspiration, when they created clothing style of the 11th Doctor, played by Matt Smith? 11th Doctor is known for wearing a tucked shirt, suspenders, a bow-tie, rolled up trousers, a jacket and boots. Except for the bow-tie, everything else fits within traditional skinhead style. Were skinheads' "boots and braces" among sources for the Doctor's clothing designers, and who else were?

**Note:** by [*skinheads*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinhead) i mean the British youth subculture of the late 60s - early 70s; see [examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=trad+skinhead&tbm=isch) of typical skinheads.

Comment: Why should they need any inspiration? Bow ties are cool. What other reason should they need?

Comment: “Except for the bow-tie, everything else fits within traditional skinhead style” — I don’t see much tweed or many waistcoats on the skinheads either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleventh_Doctor#Appearance), as reported in *Doctor Who Magazine* Issue 418:

> The eventual costume, in particular the bow-tie, was influenced by Patrick Troughton's Second Doctor, after Matt Smith fell in love with the Troughton story The Tomb of the Cybermen.

Smith's love of the Second Doctor was also [reported on Digital Spy](http://www.digitalspy.com/british-tv/s7/doctor-who/news/a332408/doctor-who-matt-smith-patrick-troughtons-my-favorite-doctor.html):

> I love Patrick Troughton. [Troughton's 1967 serial] 'Tomb of the Cybermen' is one of my favorite stories. It's so creepy," he told Newsarama. "What I think is wonderful about Troughton is he's weird and peculiar but he never asks you to find him weird and peculiar. He was a great actor. And I think the Cybermen are as scary as they've ever been in that one story.

And looking around on SciFi and Doctor Who forums dated from that time, [people made that connection right away](http://whona.realtvboard.com/t2179-11th-doctor-s-outfit):

> When I read the description of the costume I thought a re-tread of 2nd Doctor.

and:

> It's sort of a Patrick/David amalgam. I like it! (Looks more Patrick than David the more I look at it, not that that's a bad thing.)

There's also a somewhat detailed analysis from blogger comicgeekboy about the "homage" the Eleventh Doctor is to the Second aptly titled, "[The Eleventh Doctor: A loving Homage of The Second Doctor](http://comicgeekboy.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/the-eleventh-doctor-a-loving-homage-of-the-second-doctor/)".

I couldn't find any direct evidence that points to the Eleventh Doctor being inspired by [Skinhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinhead) fashions, but given the Second Doctor was on the air around the same time the Skinhead culture was becoming popular, it's not inconceivable there's an indirect influence, there.

Comment: There are those who do say skinhead. http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2014-02-09/deconstructing-doctor-who-a-fashion-expert-analyses-peter-capaldis-new-skinhead-style

Answer (score 0):

the Eleventh Doctor also originally had a stock "tweedy professor" look, especially which would identify him as the stereotype of a brilliant but socially inept type. I read an interview with, I think Steven Moffat, who said that they almost didn't go for it because it seemed too on the nose.

Comment: Have you got a link for the interview and the relevant quotes? That would improve the answer greatly.